# How do I take an unknown amount of numbers in a single line as input and assign each number to a variable?

Tags: arrays, c, scanf

I am practicing linked lists right now and I am expected to take input in the following format:

> How many numbers? 3
>
> Enter numbers : 40 7 28

Since I initially don't know how many numbers there can be, I can't use something like

`scanf("%d %d %d", &var1, &var2, &var3);`

So how can I read those numbers that are in a single line and possibly assign each of them to an array?

Comment: you can take it as one string and parse it (find spaces and use atoi)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a linked list is not necessary for this, so a simple solution would be to use a dynamically allocated array to store the elements. Use the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    int n;

    printf("How many number? ");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    int *arr = malloc(sizeof *arr * n);

    printf("Enter numbers: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        scanf("%d", &arr[i]);

    printf("The numbers you entered are: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        printf(i == (n - 1) ? "%d" : "%d ", arr[i]);

    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I prefer `&arr[i]` to `arr + i`.

Comment: creating a linked list is just the next part. I am supposed to make a linked list that would store each of the taken numbers and access them.

but  that for loop containing scanf worked for me. I guess I don't have a good understanding on have scanf works, yet :)